# Calculating mean between intersection of two polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, cell-statistics

How do I calculate the mean value (for a specific field of the attribute table) at the intersection of many polygons (.shp)?

I converted the polygons to raster based on the value I want to use to calculate the mean.

I am using ArcMap 10.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem, it was much simpler than I´d imagined. Effectively, the Cell Statistics tool was the answer, but the result I was obtaining was a raster that didn´t comprise the total area of all my rasters. Once I added the MAX extension, it worked! Here I leave the code, in case is useful for someone dealing with a similar issue.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

#set input, output and workspace folders
InputFolder_alfo = "C:/Users/Alfonsina/Desktop/Distance"
arcpy.env.workspace = InputFolder_alfo
OutputFolder_alfo = "C:\Users\Alfonsina\Desktop\Distance\output_prueba_alfo"

# Set the extent environment using MAXOF
arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

#Create a raster list of all raster files in input folder
raslist = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")

# Run cell statistics
calc = arcpy.sa.CellStatistics(raslist, statistics_type = "MEAN", 
ignore_nodata = "DATA")
calc.save(r'C:\Users\Alfonsina\Desktop\Distance\output_prueba_alfo\raster- 
04.img')
```